# How to pass a variable having integer value as request parameter

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am using the following code to send values through ajax post request.

```
        ....
    pageNumber = 2;
    var params = {};
    params['page.page'] = parseInt(pageNumber); //2
    params['page.size'] = 5;
    console.debug(params);

    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : targetUrl,
        dataType : "text",
        data : params,
        async : false,
        success : function(data){

.....rest of the code
```

on server side it receive pageNumber as string as it prints '0' for page value. But when i use 2, it prints as 2, which is what i need, so my question is 
what should i do to send the value using a variable (i.e. pageNumber)

Answer (score 0):

If you do this - `pageNumber = 2;` - pageNumber will be an integer , You don't need to parse it to int (*Unless you do this `pageNumber = "2"`;*)  -

```
 pageNumber = 2;
 var params = {};
 params['page.page'] = pageNumber;
```